# how to force the listview to refresh its view?

Tags: android, android-layout

Actually I have tried the following methods:

```
checkbox_visable=true;
fileList.notifyDataSetChanged();
listview.invalidate();
```

But it just can not recall the my specified adapter's `getview()` method for each row:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    convertView=super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    CheckBox cb=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_cb);
    if(checkbox_visable)
    cb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    return convertView;
}
```

So, any idea for me to dynamically change the UI of `ListView`?

Comment: what is your fileList? If you are using the ListView object as listview then use listview.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: fileList is the adapter for the listview.I have tried the way alike ur idea before,but it fails to work!ps:listview does not have the method:notifyDataSetChanged().But the adapter has!

Comment: try this. filelist = new FileList().. this FileList should be your custom adapteryour custom adapter. listView.setAdapter(filelist);      filelist.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Can you post the code of your custom adapter

Comment: Well,actually,i just extents the ArrayAdapter and specfies the getview() method.And the getview() method is in the post

Answer (score 1):

getview is called automaticaly when you scroll down the listview.

your view will be refreshed automaticaly

put a else condition in your code which will set the state of checkbox if the condition is false

```
if(checkbox_visable)
            cb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
else
//what you want the state of the checkbox to be
```

i think this will work.

Comment: thx for ur idea.Although ur idea does not help me directly,it point out my mistake.I should set the checkbox visable here,but i use the wrong value,View.INVISIBLE.

Answer (score 0):

Ok then try this

```
listview.setAdapter(new FileList(this, R.layout.row, your data));

And in your FileList class make the construstor of your adapter like.  

public FileList(Context context, int textViewResourceId,   String[] objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }
```

Hope this will help

Comment: thx for ur help.And i have tried it,but,it fails to work.My problem is,i want to alternate the listview'ss UI.

Comment: Sorry,nick.My problem is because of my carelessness.I use the wrong value here